# How to open a windows folder when clicking on some link on a HTML page using Asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying this code :

```
<a href="file:///C:\Programs\sort.mw">Link 1</a>
<a href="file:///C:\Videos\lecture.mp4">Link 2</a>
```

But It is not working in Google Chrome or Firefox Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your browser's console, you'll see an error like this:

> Not allowed to load local resource:

This is intentional. Chrome blocks local file access this way for security reasons. There are of course ways to [get around it](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

This links will load on your browser.

You ***don't*** have access to local strongs.

**This is web**!!!!we work on browser only(with upload files too!)

we have access to directory in **python,c,c#,c++,java,ruby,delphi,visual basic,....**